# The timing of using type qualifier, inline, in Linux kernel

Tags: c, linux

Linux kernel developers massively use the `inline` type qualifier in Linux kernel.
If used well, it can reduce the cost of a function call.
If not good, it could enlarge image size too much, which increases the cost of memory accessing.

How do they judge when to use the `inline` type qualifier?

Comment: I would suggest to rely on compiler optimisations. Option `-finline-functions` is enabled with `-O2, -O3, -Os` and that would manage this for us in a better way. Here you can read more about it : [Optimisation Flags](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html).

Comment: I would suggest reading this: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/inline-functions

Comment: @Alex The link focuses on C++ while the question is about C. There are major differences between the two wrt `inline`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Details of what effect `inline` has are specific to a compiler. Compiler-specific extensions such as `__attribute__((always_inline))` or `__forceinline` might be more useful as they have stronger and more predictable effect.

For example with Clang, the function gets inlined if its "cost" is lower than the threshold value. The threshold value is set to 225 for function without any `inline` attributes, but is multiplied by 0.333, 1.500 or 1.667 for optimization levels `-Os`, `-O2` and `-O3` respectively. With `inline`, the threshold value is set to 487. So the effect is more noticeable when compiling with lower levels, especially when using `-Os` (75 vs 487 threshold). You can check and experiment with Clang's "Optimization Output" at https://godbolt.org.

Compilers do not require `inline` keyword to inline the function. Although there are still situation when inlining will be disabled for some functions, unless `inline` keyword is used. For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48621251/why-fvisibility-inlines-hidden-is-not-the-default/48621754#48621754) GCC won't inline functions with "default" visibility on ELF targets when building shared objects (`-fPIC` flag) unless `-fno-semantic-interposition` is specified.

The most common advise will be to "profile" the code, but I don't find it very useful as you won't be able to check all possible combinations of `inline` keyword on all functions. It all comes with experience: C programmers usually know how the code generated by the compiler will look like, they also know what code they want to get in the end.

Currently, main goals of `inline` in C are:

- To suppress warnings for unused `static inline` functions (that come from headers)
- To implement `extern inline` functions.

---

Clang inlining can be manipulated [through LLVM parameters](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2014-July/074373.html) `-inline-threshold` and `-inlinehint-threshold`.

---

In C++ `inline` has additional meaning - inline functions generate "weak" symbols, duplicates of which have to be removed by the linker. In some cases function are treated as marked with `inline` implicitly, but only semantically. Further adding `inline` keyword increases inlining threshold at least on [Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/yZM9Ai) (from a normal level to an "inline" level).

Comment: "C programmers usually know how the code generated by the compiler will look like, they also know what code they want to get in the end." <= This. +1