# C++ small function not inlining

Tags: c++, inlining, lto

I have a hot and critical path function (about 45% of `cycles:ppp` as per `perf record`) in my C++17 application that is not being inlined as I would expect. It's a tiny function -- it simply returns the value of an atomic pointer member. The disassembly confirms that the function is just four assembly instructions, including the `retq`. Furthermore, there is only a single caller of this function in the entire build. I've even declared this function as `__attribute__((always_inline))`. Yet, there's a call and return to this function being generated.

The caller is in file A and the callee is in file B.

Some additional notes:

- I'm compiling with `-O3` and `-march=native`
- The callee is declared `const` and doesn't access any static members
- I'm doing link-type optimization via `-flto` when linking
- I'm using icc (ICC) 19.0.3.199 to compile
- The functions are simple member functions that are `const` and not templates, all with a dozen or fewer x86 assembly instructions

Actually, I've simplified a bit -- there are actually two places where this lack of inlining is happening in my application. File B has a function F1, which calls File A's F2, which calls File B's F3 (F2 and F3 are the ones listed above).

File A:

```
F2() {
  F3();
}
```

File B:

```
F1() {
  F2();
}

F3() {}
```

How can I get all of these to inline into one function? Another more fundamental question: can a function defined in a different file be inlined (perhaps using LTO)?

Comment: You have simplified too much. What is in header what is in source.

Comment: All function definitions are in source; headers just have declarations

Comment: Though compilers can do cross translation unit optimizations this is harder and requires you to set up the compiler correctly. To get inlining to work in the simplest case put the inlined function definition into the header file. If the functions are simple one liners this should not cause any issues (you will need to mark them as `inline` to be legal C++)

Comment: Are you building with `-fPIC` by any chance? Because ICC seems to _never_ inline non-inline function due to possible function interposition. And `-fno-semantic-interposition` is not supported by ICC.

Comment: @StaceyGirl actually I am building with `-fPIC`

Comment: When everything fails, you can always write a macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PS

The `always_inline` attribute probably does not mean what you think it means. Normally g++ does not inline anything when there are no optimizations turned on (as this makes debugging easier, I assume). By adding this attribute (`always_inline`) the compiler will inline when not optimizing (probably not what you want) but this does not make a function that was not inline(able) into one that can or will be inline(ed).

see: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html

Given your comments you have the following:

File A.h

```
void F2();
```

File B.h

```
void F1();
void F3() __attribute__((always_inline));
```

File A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

void F2() {
  F3();
}
```

File B.cpp

```
#include "B.h"
#include "A.h"

void F1() {
  F2();
}

void F3() {}
```

In the future that would be the minimal viable applications that you should have submitted as it has all the type information and enough to re-build your situation.

The code you provide is not compilable and takes a lot of cognitive load to unwind the english description you provided into compilable code.

If you have set up your compiler this can be done so that `F3()` will be inlined into `A.cpp` but that may not always be the case. To be able to do that kind of optimization either the translation unit must have access to the source of `F3()` or you must be able to cross translation unit optimizations.

You can simplify this by moving the body of `F3()` into the header file. Then it will be available for inlining directly to the translation unit.

File A.h

```
void F2();
```

File B.h

```
void F1();
void F3() __attribute__((always_inline)); // I would not add this.
                                          // Let the compiler not inline in debug mode.
inline void F3() {}
```

File A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

void F2() {
  F3();
}
```

File B.cpp

```
#include "B.h"
#include "A.h"

void F1() {
  F2();
}
```

Comment: This makes sense and your point about `always_inline` does address a misunderstanding that I had.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to have `inline` functions that are actually inlined is to define them in the same translation unit (for example, in the header file), and use the [`inline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline) specifier.

There are no provisions in Standard C++ for inlining functions across translation units, but sometimes it can be done by a compiler as part of an LTO (IPO, WPO) extension.

ICC calls it [Interprocedural Optimization (IPO)](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/optimization-and-programming-guide/interprocedural-optimization-ipo.html) and the compile flag you're looking for is `-ipo`.

See also [Using IPO](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/optimization-and-programming-guide/interprocedural-optimization-ipo/using-ipo.html).

---

<sup>Note: there is also [`-inline-level=2`](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/compiler-options/compiler-option-details/inlining-options/inline-level-ob.html) but that is already set from `-O2` onwards.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Some compilers (GCC, ICC, but not Clang) will never inline functions with public visibility on ELF targets when building shared object (`-fPIC` flag). This due to possibility of the function to be replaced by a new one in the main executable.

If you want them to be inlined you can try the following:

- Put the function in a header file and use `inline`.
- With GCC use `-fno-semantic-interposition` flag which disables this behavior.
- Use protected visibility through `-fvisibility=protected` or `__attribute__((visibility("protected")))`. This doesn't always work because this might make compiler generate relocation that cannot be handled by the linker.
- Use private (`-fvisibility=hidden`) visibility if those functions do not need to be visible outside of your shared object.

[GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) on `-fsemantic-interposition` should make some things clear:

> Some object formats, like ELF, allow interposing of symbols by the
>   dynamic linker. This means that for symbols exported from the DSO, the
>   **compiler cannot perform interprocedural propagation, inlining** and
>   other optimizations in anticipation that the function or variable in
>   question may change. While this feature is useful, for example, to
>   rewrite memory allocation functions by a debugging implementation, it
>   is expensive in the terms of code quality.

Note the part about side effect which explain how `-fno-semantic-interposition` offers compiler similar guarantees as `inline`:

> With -fno-semantic-interposition the compiler assumes that if interposition happens for functions the overwriting function **will have precisely the**
>   **same semantics (and side effects).** Similarly if interposition happens
>   for variables, the constructor of the variable will be the same. The
>   flag has no effect for functions explicitly declared inline (where it
>   is never allowed for interposition to change semantics) and for
>   symbols explicitly declared weak.

You can also check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48621754/1143634).

Answer (score -1):

"Inline functions are defined in the header because, in order to inline a function call, the compiler must be able to see the function body. For a naive compiler to do that, the function body must be in the same translation unit as the call." A translation unit means a source file together with it headers that compiles to one compilation unit. So in this case you could try to declare the function in the same source file or the in the included header.